# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with AndroidAsyncHttp

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-async-http

I'm trying to run `AsyncHttpClient` every second via a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. This works fine when I run it on its own, but when I put it in the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` it returns the following error:

`IllegalArgumentException: Synchronous ResponseHandler used in AsyncHttpClient`
https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/751

What am I doing wrong? It seems I'm just putting an async task in another thread, why does this force it into sync mode?

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor update_queue = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
long period = 1000; // the period between successive executions
update_queue.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RestClientUsage(), 0, period, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);



class RestClientUsage implements Runnable{
    public void getDriverStatus() throws JSONException {
        RestClient.get("ui_state", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                DriverStatus driverStatus = new DriverStatus().deserializeJson(response);
                // Do something with the response
                System.out.println(driverStatus);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            getDriverStatus();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public class RestClientUsage {
private static final String BASE_URL = "myURL";

private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
}
```

Comment: Upload the full page I can't tell what packages you're using.

Comment: sorry @PhilipRego  , http://loopj.com/android-async-http/